# Taking second partial derivative of spherically symmetrical wavefunction $\psi(r)$ with respect to $x$ only

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

I am currently studying *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht. In chapter **2.9 Spherical Waves**, when discussing the spherical coordinates $x = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)$, $y = r \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $z = r \cos(\theta)$, the author says that the Laplacian operator is

$$\nabla^2 = \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \left( r^2 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \right) + \dfrac{1}{r^2 \sin(\theta)} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}} \left( \sin(\theta) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right) + \dfrac{1}{r^2 \sin^2 \theta} \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}. \tag{2.67}$$

I just [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3734106/356308) how this is derived. User David Quinn commented with [this](https://planetmath.org/derivationofthelaplacianfromrectangulartosphericalcoordinates), showing me that this derivation was far more tedious than I had expected.

The author then continues as follows:

> We can obtain this result without being familiar with Eq. (2.67). Start with the Cartesian form of the Laplacian, Eq. (2.61); operate on the spherically symmetrical wavefunction $\psi(r)$; and convert each term to polar coordinates. Examining only the $x$-dependence, we have
> $$\dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}}$$
> and
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{r^2}} \left( \dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}} \right)^2 + \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \dfrac{\partial^2{r}}{\partial{x}^2}$$

I don't understand why the second derivative with respect to $x$ is $\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{r^2}} \left( \dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}} \right)^2 + \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \dfrac{\partial^2{r}}{\partial{x}^2}$. We have that $\psi$ is only a function of $r$, so should we not get

$$\dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{x}^2} = \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}} \dfrac{\partial^2{r}}{\partial{x}^2}?$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a typo in what you wrote. You have a $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}$ on both sides of your equation.

Anyway, you can just use the product and chain rule. Start with
$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$$
We know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$, so then
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial r^2}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial r^2}\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was indeed a typo (now fixed). With regards to $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)$, I understand that we get $\left( \dfrac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}} \right)^2 \dfrac{\partial^2{\psi}}{\partial{r}^2}$, but I don't see where the $\dfrac{\partial^2{r}}{\partial{x}^2} \dfrac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{r}}$ comes from.

Comment: The product rule is $(ab)'=a'b+b'a$. Use $a=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$ and $b=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$. Then $b'=\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2}$.

Comment: I think I was confused as to whether $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)$ is a multiplication (not involving the product rule) or a derivative and chain rule situation. But it seems that what you're saying is that we actually use the product rule. The product rule would only be valid in this case for functions of $x$, right? Since neither $\psi$ nor $r$ are functions of $x$, I didn't consider this, and I'm still unsure how this is mathematically valid.

Comment: No, $r$ is certainly a function of $x$. $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Then since $\psi$ depends $r$, it implicitly depends on $x$.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see now.