# Gradient of a vector field in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, tensors

What is the formula for calculating the gradient of a vector field if the field is expressed in terms of curvilinear coordinates like spherical or cylindrical systems?

Comment: [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Differentiation).

Comment: My [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734106/laplacian-of-spherical-coordinates/3734315#3734315) here briefly goes over the important differential operators in curvilinear coordinates. Please do some research before asking questions. Important note: only works for orthogonal coordinate systems.