# Solution of 2nd order elliptic PDE in 3 variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, poissons-equation

I was deriving Low Reynolds Number Flow around a Sphere of radius R placed in uniform stream U. There I got stuck in following PDEs, which are as under - 
$\nabla^2 w = \frac{3UR}{2}(\frac{3z^2}{r^5}-\frac{1}{r^3})$ 
$\nabla^2 v = \frac{3UR}{2}(\frac{3zy}{r^5})$ 
$\nabla^2 u = \frac{3UR}{2}(\frac{3zx}{r^5})$
where r = $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

I need their solutions in the form - 
$w = U(\frac{3}{4}\frac{Rz^2}{r^3}(\frac{R^2}{r^2}-1)+1-\frac{3}{4}\frac{R}{r}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{R^3}{r^3})$ 
$v = U(\frac{3}{4}\frac{Rzy}{r^3}(\frac{R^2}{r^2}-1))$ 
$u = U(\frac{3}{4}\frac{Rzx}{r^3}(\frac{R^2}{r^2}-1))$

I was unable to find any appropriate method to solve them. Any help in solving the PDEs appropriately will be of great use. Thanks!

Comment: I see **three** partial differential equations here. I'm confused.

Comment: @K.defaoite Oh yeah, I edited the question. These are 3 PDEs.

Comment: What assumptions are we allowed to make about $u,v,w$ ? In particular, are we allowed to assume they have spherical symmetry? This will make the problem *considerably* easier. To see a formula for the Laplacian operator in spherical coordinates, see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734106/laplacian-of-spherical-coordinates/3734315#3734315).

Comment: @K.defaoite I’m not sure if they have spherical symmetry. But I guess we can try assuming it here.